# "whose apple is that" or "whose is that apple"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

Are both of the following sentence structures correct?

> Whose is that apple?
>
> Whose apple is that?

Can the word order be shuffled like this? There does not seem to be missing any clarity in either sentence.

I guess I would use such different word ordering to be able to put emphasis on certain words:

> Whose is that **apple**?
>
> Whose apple is **that**?

But is it allowed?

Comment: Both are correct.  The former is preferred by some who prefer to (or erroneously believe they need to) not end a sentence with a dangling preposition.  The latter is by far the more common way to ask this question in typical speech.

Comment: "That" is not a preposition, PMV; it is a demonstrative determinative

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Whose hat is this?” vs. “Whose is this hat?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40307/whose-hat-is-this-vs-whose-is-this-hat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. In:

- Whose is that apple?

"whose" is an interrogative pronoun and, syntactically speaking, the subject complement (SC). This can be demonstrated by the fact that the natural reply will be:

- It (=That apple)'s **mine**. ("mine" is a possessive pronoun and the SC of the sentence).

Instead, in:

- Whose apple is that?

"whose" is an interrogative determiner that accompanies "apple". The whole phrase, "whose apple", is the SC. Proof of this is that the natural reply will be:

- It/That's **my** apple. (where "my" is a possessive determiner that modifies "apple", with the whole phrase, "my apple", being the SC of the sentence.)