# "Whose...is" vs "Whose is"

Tags: verbs, questions, pronouns

> **Whose** painting **is** this?
>
> **Whose is** this painting?

Is the second question grammatical? Do both questions focus on the same part of speech?

Comment: They are both OK. Syntactically, in the first "whose" is determiner to the noun "painting", while in the second it is a fused determiner-head. The stress can be on any of the words, depending on the intended meaning.

Comment: For more information see: ["whose apple is that" or "whose is that apple"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141595/whose-apple-is-that-or-whose-is-that-apple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both forms are grammatical and have the same structure in terms of parts of speech. Your second ordering ("Whose is this painting?") is antiquated; you should use the first ordering ("Whose painting is this?") in modern speech and writing.